# addEventListener 's malfunction on my computer's browser

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I write code perfectly which was written in edu-book. However, it doesn't work!

I think window.addEventListener have occured the problem. When I amended code to other one which not used addEventListener func, js and html source work very well. I tried changing browsers (Chrome, Explorer) changing computers, but not on OS.

And also such as imgPlayer.addEventListener was not work too. I don't know why addEventListener doesn't work on browser.

JS:

```
window.addEventListener("load",drawScreen,false);

var imgBackground = new Image();
imgBackground.src = "img/background.jpg";
imgBackground.addEventListener("load",drawScreen,false);

var imgPlayer = new Image();
imgPlayer.src = "img/player.jpg";
imgPlayer.addEventListener("load",drawScreen,false);

function drawScreen()
{
  var theCanvas = document.getElementsById("GameCanvas");
  var Context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");

  Context.fillStyle = "#000000";
  Context.fillRect(0,0,800,600);
  Context.drawImage(imgBackground,0,0);

  Context.drawImage(imgPlayer,350,250);
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
  <head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
    <title> 총알 피하기 </title>
    <script src = "DodgeGame.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div style="position: absolute; top: 25px; left: 25px">
    <canvas id="GameCanvas" width="800" height="600">
      지원 ㄴㄴ해
    </canvas>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should always keep your browser developer tools open to check for errors. In this case (possibly among other things), you've written `getElementsById` instead of `getElementById` — there is no "s" in the function name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are having is in this line:

```
var theCanvas = document.getElementsById("GameCanvas");
```

The method `getElementsById()` does not exist - it should be `getElementById()`. Replace the above line of code with this one:

```
var theCanvas = document.getElementById("GameCanvas");
```

And your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to declare your handler function inline

```
  window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    console.log("Tutte le risorse hanno terminato il caricamento!");
  });
```